# Differentiating SQL ID, Individual user, and AD group

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication

Is there a way to somehow know if a certain login is a SQL ID(SQL authentication login)? I am currently using `xp_logininfo [User\ADGroup], 'all'` to differentiate between the two but I don't know how I can detect or know if a login I get from the sp_who2 is a SQL ID.

Possible approach would be just look for IDs that doesn't have any domain prefix "DIR\" or "DS\". But is there any other way to know if it's a SQL login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in [`sys.server_principals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx). The `type` column will reveal the login type:

> S = SQL login
>   U = Windows login
>   G = Windows group
>   R = Server role
>   C = Login mapped to a certificate
>   K = Login mapped to an asymmetric key

Comment: Yes I can use this to check for the SQL ID, but I was looking for another way since the windows user ID like DIR\Gandalf may also belong to a ADgroup. But in any case, I will be using this in conjuction with the xp_logininfo to further check the ID.

Thank you for the help!